# Display full taxon path from NCBI GI number

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I prepared the following script that takes a GI ID number from NCBI that I prepared in my tsv file and prints the scientific name associated with the ID:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::DB::Taxonomy;

my ($filename) = @ARGV;
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Unable to open "$filename": $!};

while(<>) {
        my ($taxonid, $counts) = (split /\t/);
        for my $each($taxonid) {
                print "$each\n";
                my $db = Bio::DB::Taxonomy->new(-source => 'entrez');
                my $taxon = $db->get_taxon(-taxonid => $taxonid);
                print "Taxon ID is $taxon->id, \n";
                print "Scientific name is ", $taxon->scientific_name, "\n";
        }
}
```

With this script, I receive the following:

```
1760

Taxon ID is Bio::Taxon=HASH(0x33a91f8)->id,
```

Scientific name is Actinobacteria

### What I want to do

Now the next step is for me to list the full taxon path of the bacteria in question. So for the above example, I want to see `k__Bacteria; p__ Actinobacteria; c__ Actinobacteria` as output. Furthermore, I want the GI IDs on my table to be repliaced with this full taxon path.

In which direction should I go?

Answer (score 0):

First, I notice you open `$filename` which is your first command line argument, but you don't use the file pointer `$fh` you created.

So, these two lines are not needed in your case because you already do the trick with `<>`

```
my ($filename) = @ARGV;
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Unable to open "$filename": $!};
```

Next. I don't know what is inside your `filename` and your database so I cannot help you more. Can you provide an example of what is inside your database and your file?

One more thing, what I can see here is that you may not need to create your `$db` instance inside the loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::DB::Taxonomy;

my $db = Bio::DB::Taxonomy->new(-source => 'entrez');

while(<>) {
        my ($taxonid, $counts) = (split /\t/);
        for my $each($taxonid) {
                print "$each\n";
                my $taxon = $db->get_taxon(-taxonid => $taxonid);
                print "Taxon ID is $taxon->id, \n";
                print "Scientific name is ", $taxon->scientific_name, "\n";
        }
}
```

**Edit**

From your command Is is hard to help you. When you write

```
my $taxon = $db->get_taxon(-taxonid => $taxonid);
```

You receive a `Bio::Taxon` node where the documentation ca be found [here](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.924/Bio/Taxon.pm)

I don't know what `k__Bacteria; p__ Actinobacteria; c__ Actinobacteria` representy for you. Is it an information offered by a `Bio::Taxon` node?

Anyway, you can still explore `$taxon` with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# Author: Yves Chevallier
# Date:
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Bio::DB::Taxonomy;

my $db = Bio::DB::Taxonomy->new(-source => 'entrez');

while(<DATA>) {
    my ($taxonid, $counts) = (split /\t/);
    for my $each($taxonid) {
        print "$each\n";
        my $taxon = $db->get_taxon(-taxonid => $taxonid);
        print Dumper $taxon;
        print "Taxon ID is $taxon->id, \n";
        print "Scientific name is ", $taxon->scientific_name, "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
12 1760
```

Comment: My tab-delimited file contains two columns. The first column contains a single ID number in each row (eg. 1760), and the second column has the amount of sequences associated with that ID number.